# Parallel execution in protractor cucumber framework

Tags: protractor

I am trying parallel execution for angular application using protractor-cucumber-framework , i have tried with 2 types of capabilities but i am able to only last executed feature file json report , below are the 2 types of capabilities that i have used.

1. `capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      shardTestFiles: 'true',
      maxInstances: 3,
   },`
2. `multiCapabilities: [
   {
   shardTestFiles: true,
   browserName:'chrome',
   },
   {
   shardTestFiles: true,
   browserName: 'internet explorer',
   }
   ]`

My cucumber opts look like this:

```
cucumberOpts: {
  require:[ 'Generic_Protractor/StepDefinitions//*.js', 
  'Generic_Protractor/Support//*.js' ],
  format: [ 'json:Generic_Protractor/Report/cucumber_report.json', 'pretty' ],
  plugin : "pretty",
  keepAlive: false
}
```

Please help me out to get complete json report.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this will help you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499847/how-to-make-sharded-protractor-tests-report-after-all-tests-finish-instead-of-p

Answer (score 0):

protractor-cucumber-framework should be appending the pid to the log file to make them unique. See https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework#formatters-when-tests-are-sharded-or-with-multi-capabilities. There's currently no way to get them all in to one file, but it shouldn't be too hard to do some post processing on the multiple files to combine them.