# How to generate consolidated report while executing the protractor test scripts in parallel?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have 15 specs in my protractor suite. I want to run these scripts in parallel and, want to generate consolidated report out of this execution.

I was able to run the scripts in parallel by adding the tag 'shardTestFiles: true" in config file. But, I could not get consolidated report (getting the result of lastly executed spec only in the report).

I am looking for solution to generate consolidated report while executing the protractor scripts in parallel.

Note: Using jasmine reporter to generate report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499847/how-to-make-sharded-protractor-tests-report-after-all-tests-finish-instead-of-p ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter) reporter and provide an option for consolidating your test results. For example:

```
 var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: 'testReports/',
            screenshotsFolder: 'images',
            takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
            consolidateAll: true,
            consolidate: true,
            cleanDestination: false
        }));
```

Comment: The  configuration you have mentioned above did not consolidate the report. But, I followed another stackoverflow question which was raised with same intention as mine: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336025/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter-doesnt-consolidate-results-for-all-test-when/39347368#39347368

Following config file had what I wanted: https://github.com/tyaga001/multi-capability-reporting-protractor-/blob/master/protractor.conf.js

Answer (score 0):

I followed the approach mentioned below to fulfill my need.

1. I kept below code in onPrepare section of config file. This will generate a report for every spec.

   ```
   onPrepare() {
   return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
           browser.getCapabilities().then(function (value) {
             reportName = value.get('webdriver.remote.sessionid') + '_' + value.get('browserName') + '_' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1E16); // eslint-disable-line
             jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
               new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                 savePath: 'e2e/Results',
                 screenshotsFolder: 'images',
                 takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
                 consolidate: true,
                 consolidateAll: true,
                 cleanDestination: false,
                 fileName: "my-report.html",
                 fileName: "regression-test-report.html",
                 fileNamePrefix: reportName,
               })
             );
             fulfill();
           })
         });
       });
   },
   ```

   And kept following code in afterLaunch section which will consolidate all the reports generated in onPrepare section:

   ```
   afterLaunch: function afterLaunch() {
       var fs = require('fs');
       var output = '';
       fs.readdirSync('e2e/Results/').forEach(function(file){
         if(!(fs.lstatSync('e2e/Results/' + file).isDirectory()))
           output = output + fs.readFileSync('e2e/Results/' + file);
       });
       fs.writeFileSync('e2e/Results/RegressionTestReport.html', output, 'utf8');
     }
   ```

**Challenge faced after above configuration:** I was able to consolidate the report through parallel execution by writing above configuration in config file. But, If I run the script second time, the report will consolidate that as well ( which I don't want to do ).  Making the tag 'cleanDestination: true' deleted each spec once its execution ends. So, it did not work.

**How I resolved this challenge?**: I was running the script in jenkins using shell script. So, I wrote shell command 'rm -fr e2e/Results' to delete report folder before the execution of the script. So, the report will be deleted every time and a fresh consolidated report will be generated with latest execution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter` combined with suggestions in the linked answer but did not like the output. I like the output generated by `protractor-html-reporter-2` which works on the xml file produced by `jasmine-reporters`. But that does not have any option to work with reports generated by multiple instances of browsers. After failing to find an ideal solution, I ended up doing following in the protractor config js file:

```
// add relevant packages in package.json
'use strict';
const HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');
const jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
const moment = require('moment');
const os = require('os');
const xmldoc = require('xmldoc');
...
const DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD-HHmmss-SSS'; // use any other format that gives unique timestamp
const reportDir = path.join(__dirname, '../report');
...
exports.config = {
    ...
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        maxInstances: 2,
        shardTestFiles: true,
    },
    beforeLaunch: async function () {
        // clean up report directory
        fs.emptyDirSync(reportDir);
    }, 
    onPrepare: async function () {
         const NOW = moment().format(DATE_FORMAT);
         const reportName = 'index-' + NOW;
         jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
             consolidateAll: true,
             savePath: reportDir,
             filePrefix: reportName,
         }));
    },
    onComplete: async function () {
        // do something after each instance of browser is closed
    },
    afterLaunch: async function (exitCode) {
        // do something after ALL instances of browser are closed
        await consolidateJasmineXmlReports();
    },
    ...     
},
...
async function consolidateJasmineXmlReports() {
    // there may be better ways to write xml out but this works for me
    const files = fs.readdirSync(reportDir).filter(fn => fn.endsWith('.xml'));
    let disabledSum = 0;
    let errorsSum = 0;
    let failuresSum = 0;
    let testsSum = 0;
    let timeSum = 0;
    const allTestSuiteNodes = [];
    for (const file of files) {
        const pathToXml = reportDir + path.sep + file;
        console.log('Reading xml report file: ' + pathToXml);
        const xml = fs.readFileSync(pathToXml);
        const xmlDoc = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(xml);
        const disabled = parseInt(xmlDoc.attr.disabled);
        const errors = parseInt(xmlDoc.attr.errors);
        const failures = parseInt(xmlDoc.attr.failures);
        const tests = parseInt(xmlDoc.attr.tests);
        const time = parseFloat(xmlDoc.attr.time);
        disabledSum += disabled;
        errorsSum += errors;
        failuresSum += failures;
        testsSum += tests;
        timeSum += time;

        const testSuiteNodes = xmlDoc.childrenNamed('testsuite');
        allTestSuiteNodes.push(testSuiteNodes);
    }

    let startXml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`;
    startXml += `<testsuites disabled="` + disabledSum + `" errors="` + errorsSum + `" failures="` + failuresSum + `" tests="` + testsSum + `" time="` + timeSum + `">`;
    const endXml = '</testsuites>';
    allTestSuiteNodes.push(endXml);
    const finalXml = startXml + allTestSuiteNodes.join('\n');
    fs.writeFileSync(reportDir + path.sep + 'consolidated.xml', finalXml, 'utf8');
        
    const testConfig = {            
        outputPath: reportDir,
        outputFilename: 'consolidated',
        ...
    };

    new HTMLReport().from(reportDir + path.sep + 'consolidated.xml', testConfig);
}
```

We use Jenkins to run the tests and the report created by above displays well in Jenkins and also shows up accurately on the report displayed by `Open Blue Ocean Jenkins` plugin.

See Also:

- [Protractor config file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts)
- [Setting up jasmine reporter](https://praveendavidmathew.medium.com/creating-html-reports-for-protractor-7d9830ebf428)